# Densly Populated Index PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have been searching for an answer for this question. I am learning PL/SQL programming and I came across the term densely populated index.  I can't find a good definition of densely populated index. What does that mean in PL/SQL?

Comment: Is your context in dense vs sparse collections?

Comment: Maybe the context is a comparison between b-tree and bitmap index.

Comment: Not sure but this might be of use to you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50248/what-is-difference-between-primary-index-secondary-index-unique-index-and-norm

Answer (score 0):

A densely populated index is one that is sequential integers meaning there are no gaps and a fixed length. SQL Collections are densely populated indexes because a sequential set of integers are used and they’re set up with pre-allocated space.

From Oracle Database 12c PL/SQL Programming by Michael McLaughlin